# How can i set the value from the last row in an specific column in a variable in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, oledb

I'm develop an application using forms in vb.net with visual studio 2019

I have code in the event click for one button

```
Dim oda As New OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ods As New DataSet
Dim consulta As String
Dim cadena As New OleDbConnection
Dim comando As New OleDbCommand

     Try
        cadena.Open()

        comando = New OleDbCommand("Insert into QRQC (Nombre,NumControl,Fecha,Hora,Turno)" &
                                   "values(txt_nombre,txt_numControl,lbl_fecha,lbl_hora,cBox_turno)", cadena)

        consulta = "Select *From QRQC"
        oda = New OleDbDataAdapter(consulta, cadena)
        ods.Tables.Add("QRQC")
        oda.Fill(ods.Tables("QRQC"))


        Dim row As Integer
        row = ods.Tables("QRQC").Rows.Count - 1


        courrentId = ods.Tables("QRQC")(row)("ID_QRQC").ToString()
        frm_newPt2.lbl_folioQRQC.Text = courrentId

        cadena.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error al generar el registro en la base de datos", vbCritical, "Aviso")
        Console.WriteLine(ex)
        cadena.Close()
        GoTo skip
    End Try
```

Everything goes perfectly, but when I delete some record on my DB this part of the code always return the value 102

```
courrentId = ods.Tables("QRQC")(row)("ID_QRQC").ToString()
```

[image: Value returned to variable courrentId]

[image: Courrent value of variable row]

[image: Courrent data on DB]

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: That means that the value in the `ID_QRQC` column at index `10` is `102`, plain and simple. There's no point looking in the database to see what's in your `DataTable` because they are not the same thing. If you want your `DataTable` sorted a specific way then you should make that happen in your code, rather than relying on the default sort being what you want. If what you really want is the maximum value in that column then that's what you should get, rather than the last value.

Comment: Maybe if you tell us want you want to do with `courrentId` we could provide a better approach.

Comment: What is the value of 'row'?

Comment: i want to get the last record on my DataTable, row is the value of the count of the total rows in my table. courrentId its the value correspondent to the last record it means, the last row, in my DB my last row its 10, in that position i have the value 106, 102 corresponds to the row 6

Comment: You need to check whether 'ods.Tables("QRQC")' is same as the data in the database.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your insert command is wrong, and will not work.

You have "values(txt_nombre. etc etc."

But that is just a string and NOT the actual values from the form. So you are actually going to "instert txt_nombre" into that table and NOT the value of that label or text box on the form!!!

So you need to fix and get your insert command working FIRST.

And if this is just editing data then consider using the data binder, since navigation, editing, deleting and saving of data to/from the table can occur 100% automatic whiteout ANY code on your part.

so first up is to fix that insert command. You can't JUST use a string with the names of the controls else that would actually as noted try to insert the names of the controls as text and NOT the values of the controls.

And lets clean up a few other things. No need for a dataset, since a dataset is a SET of tables - we only dealing with one table (so use a data table).

But as noted, before we mess with data tables, we have to fix that insert command.

It will, can look like this:

```
    Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "Insert into QRQC (Nombre,NumControl,Fecha,Hora,Turno) " &
                        "VALUES(@nombre,@numControl,@fecha,@hora,@turno)"

    Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand(strSQL,
            New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.TestDB))

        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@nombre", OleDbType.Integer).Value = txt_nombre.Text
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@numControl", OleDbType.Integer).Value = txt_numControl.Text
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@fecha", OleDbType.Integer).Value = lbl_fecha.Text
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@hora", OleDbType.Integer).Value = lbl_hora.Text
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@turno", OleDbType.Integer).Value = txt_nombre.Text

        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()

    End Using
```

So you have to "replace" the string values in the sql with the ACTUAL values you are using.

You also don't show where/how you setup your connection to the database. I guessed that you used the applications settings and the connection builder - so you have to change TestDB to your actual connection that you used.

The above will thus get  your insert command working.

At that point, you can post a new question in that after you do a insert, how to get the new autonumber primary key, or whatever else you wanted to do, but your insert statement as written will not work.

As noted, perhaps it better to use data bound controls. This will result in a Access like design experience, and you not having to write ANY code to edit a table in vb.net.

And it not clear if the control names I used are correct (or they are even controls on the form), but if they are, then ".Text" is required to grab the values. You have to of course change (check) that the control names I used and guessed are correct.

You also have to change the data type "integer" I used in above to the correct data types. For text I recommend you use .VarWChar